# Reference/Failed to load js Error: Vanilla Javascript not recognizing method and loading script

Tags: html

The following has occurred:

```
ReferenceError: anputAccept is not defined]
```

`<script type="text/javascript" src="tshirt1.js"></script>` <--this is failing to load.

I have created a .js file that has a method in it named anputAccept. This is located within Script tags in HTML at the bottom of the body tags.

```
document.getElementById("pushme").addEventListener("click",inputAccept);
```

The actual method is set like this in .js

```
 function anputAccept() { //Statements here };
```

Can anyone explain exactly what is going on, and why the script fails to run? Why is there a Reference Error? This is caused because the script fails to load?

Comment: check the browser console and make sure the script actually loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `<script type="text/javascript" src="tshirt1.js"></script>` to the bottom of the HTML page or you can you can try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("pushme").addEventListener("click",inputAccept);
};
```